# If a functor commutes with all filtered colimits, then does it commute with all existing colimits?

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory

Suppose $F: C \to D$ is a functor between $C$ and $D$. If for all [filtered diagram](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04AX) $I$, both the colimits $\mathsf{colim}F(I)$, $F(\mathsf{colim} I)$ exist and

$$
\mathsf{colim}F(I) = F(\mathsf{colim} I)
$$
Then for any other arbitrary diagram $J$, if both the colimits $\mathsf{colim}F(J)$, $F(\mathsf{colim} J)$ exist, one always have

$$
\mathsf{colim}F(J) = F(\mathsf{colim} J)
$$
?

I got the following proof:

*Proof*: Since if $\mathsf{colim}J$ exists, adding $\mathsf{colim}J$  to the diagram $J$, i.e., considering the colimit cone, it's a filtered diagram. Denote this diagram as $K$, then from the following properties:

- cocones are filtered diagrams
- the (co)limit of a (co)cone is its apex
- the image of a (co)cone is still a (co)cone

$K$ is filtered diagram, $\mathsf{colim}K = \mathsf{colim} J$ and

$$
\mathsf{colim}F(J) = \mathsf{colim}F(K) = F(\mathsf{colim} K) = F(\mathsf{colim} J)
$$

Is this argument correct? I am hesitant. It seems OK but too good to be true.

Comment: The forgetful functor from rings to sets commutes with filtered colimits, but not with all colimits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is false.  For example, the forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{Group} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves filtered colimits, but not binary coproducts for instance.

I think the invalid step is in the assertion that $\operatorname{colim} F(J) = \operatorname{colim} F(K)$.

Comment: Yeah...It does not hold. It holds only if $F$ commutes with $J$, then this is circular. Thank you very much^^